# Failing to obtain services from iOS peripheral using chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app

I have an iOS app which advertises itself successfully using a CBPeripheralManager. In a Chrome App, I have successfully discovered the device (hence obtaining its address).

I have added a service with a custom UUID to the peripheral manager. didAddService is called (after the peripheral manager is powered on), and so I assume that part is successful.

I call chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.connect(device address) in the Chrome app. The callback function is called without issue, and so I believe the connection is successful. There is no function called within the app when the connection has occurred - should there be?

I then call chrome.bluetooth.getServices(device address) in the Chrome app. An array of services is returned, however the array is empty. I believe it should return an array of length 1, not 0.

Am I overlooking something? Why are no services being returned? Should any of the peripheralManager functions be called during these operations?

Connect code:

```
function connect(address) {

  /* Connect persistently to the device. */
  chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.connect(address, {persistent: true}, function() {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {

      /* If we click a green device, we get this. We should try and handle it
         earlier. e.g. by removing the listener, or instead using the click
         to disconnect the device. */
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError.message == 'Already connected')
        setDeviceConnected(address);

      /* Print error and exit. */
      console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Successfully connected to ' + address);
    setDeviceConnected(address);
    // getDeviceService();
    getDeviceServices(address);
  });

  return true;
}
```

Get services code:

```
function getDeviceServices(address) {
  chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.getServices(address, function(services) {
    console.log('services.length: ' + services.length);
  });
}
```

Peripheral setup code:

```
- (void)setupPeripheral {
  _serviceName = SERVICE_NAME;
  _serviceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE_UUID_STRING];
  _characteristicUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_STRING];

  _peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

  _characteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:_characteristicUUID
                                                     properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead | CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify
                                                     value:nil
                                                     permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

  _service = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:_serviceUUID primary:YES];
  _service.characteristics = @[_characteristic];


  NSLog(@"Peripheral set up");
}
```

Start advertising (add the service just before we start advertising):

```
/* Start advertising */
- (void)startAdvertising {
  NSLog(@"Starting advertising...");

  NSDictionary *advertisment = @{
                                 CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[self.serviceUUID],
                                 CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: self.serviceName
                                 };
  [self addServices];
  [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:advertisment];
}
```

Call to start advertising within didUpdateState:

```
/* Did update state */
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
  switch (peripheral.state) {
    case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn:
      NSLog(@"peripheralStateChange: Powered On");
      // When the bluetooth has turned on, start advertising.
      [self startAdvertising];
      break;
```

**Update**

On connecting to the peripheral app with OSX app LightBlue, an alert shows up on the app to request a pairing. Then LightBlue can read characteristics from the app. When connecting with the Chrome app, the pairing alert does not show up.

Comment: Where are you adding the service you created to your peripheral like peripheral.addservice(service)

Comment: I add the service just before the peripheral manager starts advertising, see code snippet 4, [self addServices]. It is a simple function: [_peripheralManager addService:_service];

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this problem myself.  I've developed a simple app that scans for devices and their services, but all devices found always report back an empty array of services.  I have this problem on both OsX and ChromeOS.

There's an exception to this: when the device has previously been paired, I was able to get the services array on ChromeOS.  This is confusing to me, since nothing I've read anywhere says a device has to be manually paired first, and there's no programatic way to pair a device one discovered.

EDIT: Upgrading to Chrome 53 fixed the problem.  The site linked in louisdeb's answer is related to web-bluetooth, not chrome.bluetooth, so characteristics may actually work.

Comment: When you try to connect to an unknown device, the os itself pops up a notification for pairing.

Comment: I see. The chrome bluetoothLowEnergy page says that the api is supported on OSX, Windows and ChromeOS, so I was hoping this wasn't an OS related issue.

Comment: @BhavukJain That's for web-bluetooth, the question is related to chrome bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Having chatted to web-bluetooth developers at W3C, I have now been able to discover services from the device, by **updating chrome** from v51 to v52 (apparantly also v53 works).

However currently (though I am yet to try it out), reading characteristics is currently unsupported for OSX, as seen [here](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md).

(I have not yet looked into it but [this](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno) may provide some options on how to overcome the issues described here.)